# Does Azure have an IaC tool just like CloudFormation of AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform

I compared GCP with AWS, the IaC tools of both are 'Deploy Manager' and 'CloudFormation'. What about Azure? Does Azure have such a tool (in order to compete with the two largest Public Cloud Provider)?

Comment: azure is bigger than GCP, just so you know

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you are looking for ARM Templates. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview#template-deployment

They allow for declarative provisioning syntax.

Answer (score 12):

AWS has “Amazon Cloud Formation”, Azure has “Azure Resource Manager”, and for the Google Cloud there is “Deployment Manager”. They all provide a way to define your cloud infrastructure resources using a declarative language, which you can then put in a git repository, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Plus, there is also vendor-neutral Terraform.